# HandBrakeCLI Video Rotation Not Working

Tags: linux, video, video-processing, handbrake

I have been using the following command to rotate video 90 degree clockwise

```
HandBrakeCLI -i ip.mp4 -o op.mp4 --preset="Universal" --rotate="4"
```

Which is working properly in my windows machine. When i try with the same command on linux server video rotation is not working. Also tried these commands in linux server which are also not working

```
HandBrakeCLI -i ip.mp4 -o op.mp4 --preset="Universal", --rotate="4"
HandBrakeCLI -i ip.mp4 -o op.mp4 --preset="normal", --rotate="4"
```

Linux Server HandBrakeCLI Version - 0.9.5
Windows machine HandBrakeCLI Version - 0.9.9

Please correct me if am missing anything

Comment: that command works for me on Mac

Comment: That works for me also in my local windows machine but not in linxu server.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. This commands do not work for me on mac with HandBrakeCLI from brew

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this problem and was able to get rotate working with the [latest HandBrakeCLI](https://handbrake.fr/downloads2.php) (v1.2.2) using a slightly different set of options.

For example, the following command was successful for rotating my encoded video by 90 degrees, clockwise.

`$ HandBrakeCLI --preset="Fast 1080p30" --rotate="angle=90:hflip=0"`

The supported values are [0, 90, 180, 270]. I only tested this on macOS but don't suspect other platforms will be different.